# How to add a blank line after a specific character in a text file using sed?

Tags: sed

I want to insert and have "|" be replaced by a blank line after it.

```
inp.txt
```

```
abcd |
efgh |
ijkl |
```

```
out.txt
```

```
abcd 

efgh

ijkl
```

This is on unix. Every time I've tried

```
sed -i.bak 's/|/\n/g' inp.txt
```

All it returns is

```
abcd n
efgh n
ijkl n
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Ubuntu...

Comment: Also working on Debian.

Comment: Check for changes in `inp.txt` and not `inp.txt.bak`

Comment: @afuna: @Prvt_Yadav: `on Debain` or `on Ubuntu` doesn't say much. You probably use `GNU sed` but you should also say what version of `sed` you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\n`, you can add a backslash `\`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and continue on the next line with the command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/|/\
/g' inp.txt
```

To replace the remaining space character and `|` at the end of the line (`$`), use

```
sed -i.bak 's/ |$/\
/' inp.txt
```

You don't need the `g` flag for one replacement.

Answer (score 0):

if the pipe char is always at the end of line, then you can do this:

```
$ sed -i.bak -e '/[|]$/G' -e 's///' inp.txt
```

And otherwise, if that's not the case and/or there are one or more pipes in a line, then do this:

```
$ sed -i.bak -e 'y/|/\n/' file.txt
```

which shall transform all the pipe characters anywhere in a line to newlines.